# pandas interpolate doesnt fill null values

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, missing-data

i have this code which I load a my data to a dataframe and i try to fill up the naN values using .interpolate instead of replacing it with 0

my dataframe looks like this:

```
    weight  height  wc  hc  FBS HBA1C
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   55.6    151.0   NaN NaN 126.0   NaN
2   42.8    151.0   73.0    79.0    NaN NaN
3   60.8    155.0   NaN NaN 201.0   NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   60.0    NaN 87.0    92.0    NaN NaN
6   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   NaN NaN NaN NaN 194.0   NaN
9   57.0    158.0   95.0    90.0    NaN NaN
10  46.0    NaN 83.0    91.0    223.0   NaN
11  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
12  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
13  58.5    164.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
14  62.0    154.0   80.5    100.0   NaN NaN
15  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
16  57.0    152.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
17  62.4    153.0   88.0    99.0    NaN NaN
18  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
19  48.0    146.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
20  68.7    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
21  49.0    146.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
22  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
23  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
24  70.2    161.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
25  70.4    161.0   93.0    68.0    NaN NaN
26  61.8    143.0   91.0    98.0    NaN NaN
27  70.4    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
28  70.1    144.0   100.0   103.0   NaN NaN
29  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
318 49.0    146.0   92.0    89.0    NaN NaN
319 64.7    145.0   87.0    107.0   NaN NaN
320 55.5    149.0   81.0    101.0   NaN NaN
321 55.4    145.0   87.0    96.0    NaN NaN
322 53.1    153.0   83.0    96.0    NaN NaN
323 52.1    147.0   89.0    92.0    NaN NaN
324 68.9    167.0   96.0    100.0   NaN NaN
325 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
326 57.0    142.0   100.0   101.0   NaN NaN
327 72.5    163.0   98.0    95.0    NaN NaN
328 73.5    157.0   94.0    114.0   NaN NaN
329 61.0    160.0   90.0    89.5    NaN NaN
330 49.0    150.0   80.0    90.0    NaN NaN
331 50.0    150.0   83.0    90.0    NaN NaN
332 67.6    155.0   92.0    103.0   NaN NaN
333 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
334 78.7    162.0   99.0    101.0   NaN NaN
335 74.5    155.0   98.0    110.0   NaN NaN
336 68.0    152.0   85.0    93.0    NaN NaN
337 67.0    152.0   NaN NaN 179.1   NaN
338 NaN NaN NaN NaN 315.0   NaN
339 38.0    145.0   66.0    NaN 196.0   NaN
340 50.0    148.0   NaN NaN 133.0   NaN
341 73.5    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
342 74.5    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
343 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
344 67.0    152.0   106.0   NaN NaN NaN
345 52.0    145.0   94.0    NaN NaN NaN
346 52.0    159.0   89.0    NaN NaN NaN
347 67.0    153.0   92.0    91.0    NaN NaN
```

my code:

```
   import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('final_dataset_3.csv')

    import numpy as np
    df['weight'].replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)
    df['height'].replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)
    df['wc'].replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)
    df['hc'].replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)
    df['FBS'].replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)
    df['HBA1C'].replace(0,np.nan, inplace=True)



    df1 = df.interpolate()

    df1
```

df1 looks like this

```
weight  height  wc  hc  FBS HBA1C
    0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    1   55.600000   151.0   NaN NaN 126.000000  NaN
    2   42.800000   151.0   73.000000   79.000000   163.500000  NaN
    3   60.800000   155.0   77.666667   83.333333   201.000000  NaN
    4   60.400000   155.5   82.333333   87.666667   199.600000  NaN
    5   60.000000   156.0   87.000000   92.000000   198.200000  NaN
    6   59.250000   156.5   89.000000   91.500000   196.800000  NaN
```

after running the code, it didnt replace the naN values with a value instead replaces the values with more decimal points.

Comment: Replace `df[...].replace(..., inplace=True)` with `df[...] = df[...].replace(...)` everywhere

Comment: I doubt you need six lines of replace here. Just do `df = df.fillna(0)`, perhaps `df1 = df.fillna(0).interpolate()` might help.

Comment: ok let me try thanks

Comment: @Dark didnt work :( values remain 0.

Comment: update: it works but not all rows or columns was filled up with values.

Comment: Consider this for values at both ends, where you're extrapolating instead 
of interpolating: httpstackoverflow.com/a/35959909/6573647

Comment: @Melvin yea i guess you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this data leads me to believe that interpolating the values would be improper. Each row represents some attributes for different people. You cannot base a missing value of, say, weight on adjacent rows. I understand that you need to deal with the NaN's because much of the data will be useless when building many types of models.

Instead maybe you should fill with the mean() or median(). Here's a simple dataframe with some missing values.

```
df
Out[58]: 
   height  weight
0    54.0   113.0
1    61.0   133.0
2     NaN   129.0
3    48.0     NaN
4    60.0   107.0
5    51.0   114.0
6     NaN   165.0
7    51.0     NaN
8    53.0   147.0
9     NaN   124.0
```

To replace missing values with the mean() of the column:

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
Out[59]: 
   height  weight
0    54.0   113.0
1    61.0   133.0
2    54.0   129.0
3    48.0   129.0
4    60.0   107.0
5    51.0   114.0
6    54.0   165.0
7    51.0   129.0
8    53.0   147.0
9    54.0   124.0
```

Of course, you could easily use median() or some other method that makes sense for your data.

Comment: note: conescutive ```NaN``` s will be filled with the same numbers.

Comment: @sutan So what? Why do you think that is a bad thing in this particular case?

Comment: woah, calm down @floydn ; I'm not saying it as bad; it's just the fact of your code.